# jasmine unit test case for slider directive

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Plz see the below slider directive code

```
appCommon.directive('slider', [function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModel) {

            var mySlider = element.slider({
                tooltip: 'hide',
                value: 0,
                max: 100
            });

            scope.$watch(function () {
                return ngModel.$modelValue;
            }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                mySlider.slider('setValue', parseInt(newValue));
            });

            attr.$observe('isDisabled', function (isDisabled) {
                if (isDisabled == 'true') {
                    mySlider.slider('disable');
                }
                else {
                    mySlider.slider('enable');
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

and want to write unit test case for this ..could you please give me the exact test case for this

Answer (score 0):

Dont unit test your directives. Make a controller to contain the logic, and unit test that.

```
controller: 'SliderController',
```

Add this to your directive, and move the logic you want to test to that controller.

Comment: the above code is my directive ...just want to write test case for it how to do that

Comment: as I said, you need to make a controller in order to unit test it. You cannot test the link function.

Your link function will init your controller with scope and other stuff. Then you can unit test that